# Connecting Unity and Xamarin Android App

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, java-native-interface, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

Hi I'm trying to connect Android app using `Xamarin` with Unity 3D because I want to get `SharedPreference` items from Android to `Unity`. On Unity I run this code:

```
AndroidJavaObject AJO = null;

void Start () {
            new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.exampledata.MainActivity");
    }
```

I run on my phone and get this error in logcat :

```
I/Unity   (29805): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.exampledata.MainActivity
I/Unity   (29805): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.exampledata.MainActivity
I/Unity   (29805):      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
I/Unity   (29805):      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
I/Unity   (29805):      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
I/Unity   (29805):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
I/Unity   (29805):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
I/Unity   (29805):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)
I/Unity   (29805): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.exampledata.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.exampledata/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.exampledata/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
I/Unity   (29805):      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/Unity   (29805):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
I/Unity   (29805):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
I/Unity   (29805):      ... 6 m
```

As you can see, unity can't find the class. Do you have another ways to get the `SharedPreference` items or another ways to connecting Android (build with Xamarin on Visual Studio) with Unity 3D ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i got this from Xamarin.

> Sad but true, for now it is not possible

[image: Xamarin Support Image]

Comment: Hey, it's been 2 years, what about now?